# Application crashes when open youtube link

Tags: android, youtube

I'm using this code to open youtube link, It works before, but now it crashes.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(url));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube",
                        "com.google.android.youtube.PlayerActivity");
```

Here is logcat

```
    STACK_TRACE=android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1636)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3493)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3735)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3703)
at com.scutify.CompanyDetailActivity.onItemClick(CompanyDetailActivity.java:366)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1524)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3531)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4898)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
```

Can you tell me why it crashes? 
How to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your logCat or anything that might help show the reason for the crash? It is hard to tell what is going on without this info...

Comment: Is it intended that you have two names for your intent (`intent` and `tab5Intent`)?

Comment: @CodeMonkey @Gaetan(sorry I can't tag you): I have updated my question

Comment: You can try `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + videoId))` if you have the id of the video, or `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(youtubeUrl))` if you have a full link.

Comment: @Gaëtan: I have full link and want to open Youtube directly... Can you help????

Comment: The second Intent should work, no? I can not try at the moment. But the best option is probably the first one if you have the possibility to extract the video id

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Intent videoClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
videoClient.setData("VALID YOUTUBE LINK WITH HTTP");
videoClient.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube","com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity");
startActivity(videoClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```

The id is the identifier after the questionmark in the url. For example: youtube.com/watch?v=ID

or

```
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
videoIntent.setData(url);
videoIntent.setClassName("com.google.anddroid.youtube","com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity");
startActivity(videoIntent);
```

Comment: are you testing it in emulator or in device ?